# Python 3.4.1 Find different keep the same

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am having trouble wrapping my head around evaluating a set of data correctly. I have a set of JSON data with Numbered Keys. My Goal is to evaluate all value and increment them to equal the same value over time.

Example:
py script to run once an hour.
(1) Look at JSON Data:

```
{
"1": 100,
"10": 75,
"2": 100,
"3": 100,
"4": 100,
"5": 100,
"6": 100,
"7": 100,
"8": 100,
"9": 100
}
```

(2) Identify that key "10" is not equal to the rest.
(3) Increment Key #10's value +1 to 76

This process should repeat each hour.
When the evaluation finds that all values are equal, then it should increase the value of Key #1 by +1 to 101.
Upon next run it should increment Key #2 by +1 and so forth each run until they are equal again.

I can already work with the JSON data printing it out, select certain values, updating, etc.. My trouble is trying to figure out how the correctly evaluate the data. What kind of if then, while, etc loop or what I should do to accomplish my goal.

Comment: What happens if multiple values are 'lower'?

Comment: Also, how married are you to this data structure? Any algorithm has to start with sorting the keys and iterating, so you may as well just make this a *list* instead.

Comment: I was thinking of turning this into a list, but it is an API system so I get the response as JSON and have to reply with updates in JSON. Could I turn it into a list with the values entered in the order of there key value? So I would know which entry is which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically finding the first value that is *lower* than the preceding elements:

```
import json

data = json.loads(json_string)

first = data['1']
for key in sorted(data):
    if data[key] < first:
        data[key] += 1
        break
else:
    data['1'] += 1

json_string = json.dumps(data)
```

This'll increment the first value encountered that is lower than the value associated with `data['1']`. If there is no such value, `data['1']` is incremented instead.

Note that you may as well make this a JSON *list*:

```
json_string = "[100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 75]"
```

and the code becomes:

```
first = data[0]
for i, val in enumerate(data[1:]):
    if val < first:
        data[i] += 1
        break
else:
    data[0] += 1
```

Comment: The data comes to me via an API in JSON form. Could I turn it into a list with the values entered in the order of there key value? So I would know which entry is which? and then based in the position with in the list I could update the key via the API? Which would also be helpful as the JSON over of elements always seems to be out of order compared to its key values.

Comment: @QOps1981: it doesn't really matter all that much; the `sorted()` function takes care of handling the keys in order. Converting to a list first then back to a dictionary is not going to gain you much.

Answer (score 0):

```
data ={
"1": 100,
"10": 75,
"2": 100,
"3": 100,
"4": 100,
"5": 100,
"6": 100,
"7": 100,
"8": 100,
"9": 100
}  



import time
n = 1
while True:
    if data["10"] < data["9"]: # if 9 is greater we need to increase 10, reset n
        data["10"] += 1
        n = 1
        time.sleep(3600) # sleep for an hour
    else:
        data[str(n)] += 1
        time.sleep(3600)
        n += 1
        continue
```